# How to export terminal output to csv file in python?

Tags: python

Below is my code I want to export the output to csv file can some one help me with the last bit of code..

```py
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests


url = "https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=North+Indian+Thali&find_loc=Portland%2C+OR"

response = requests.get(url)

soup = bs(response.content,'html.parser')

content = soup.find_all('h3',attrs={'class':'css-1agk4wl'})

for links in content:
    listr = links.find('a','css-19v1rkv').get('name')
```

Comment: Remember to actually read to [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask), and then [edit] your post accordingly, with proper [markdown](/markdown) for code blocks. A good rule of thumb is that if your post has only one line of explanation, you haven't properly explained yourself yet. Say what you needed to do, what you came up with to do that, show the code you wrote, then talk about what that did and how it wasn't what you expected, _and_ what you already did to try to debug/fix the problem.

Comment: Your post and your question do not really make clear, what your exact issue or struggle is and what goal you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you all I am new to stack ... I will try my best to make post move meaningful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

url = "https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=North+Indian+Thali&find_loc=Portland%2C+OR"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(response.content, 'html.parser')
content = soup.find_all('h3', attrs={'class': 'css-1agk4wl'})

data = []  # List to store the extracted values

for links in content:
    listr = links.find('a', 'css-19v1rkv').get('name')
    data.append(listr)  # Append the value to the data list

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Values'])  # Create a DataFrame with the extracted values
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)  # Export the DataFrame to a CSV file
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I understood your approach. To first add the output to list and then using dataframs make dara and then export to csv

Comment: @ShubhamVashisht If that's what you want feel free to mark the answer as accepted.